# Count entries in mysql database by month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to gather statistics about a database that I am working with, I want to know how many entries were made in the database per month, I'm stuck because the timeframe is longer than one year, e.g. it starts in Feb 2010 and ends at the present.

Right now I am trying to do something like this:

```
startDate = `mysql -h <hostname> -u root -D build -e "select MIN(submittime) '
Start Date' from builds;"`

endDate = `mysql -h <hostname> -u root -D build -e "select MAX(submittime) 'En
d Date' from builds;"`

months = []
months.push(`mysql -h <hostname> -u root -D build -e "select count(id) 
from builds where submittime >= startDate 
and submittime <= date_add(startDate, interval 30 DAY);"`
```

etc...
Any help/ideas would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add GROUP BY MONTH(submittime).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), CONCAT(MONTH(submittime),'-',YEAR(submittime)) AS start 
   FROM builds GROUP BY start
```

or, more simply

```
SELECT COUNT(id), submittime
   FROM builds GROUP BY YEAR(submittime), MONTH(submittime)
```

Comment: this counts the total number of entries, then just gives me the earliest submittime. 359, '2010-05-27 10:48:36'

Comment: Sorry... made an error by using 'Start Date'... should have used 'submittime'... post updated.